# Flutter FCM notfications + text to speech plugin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter, text-to-speech

i am trying to make an app that reads notifications from firebase cloud messaging 
i am sending notifications with a node program and reading it in flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';




void main(){runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: ' Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging  = new FirebaseMessaging();

  FlutterTts flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
  int _counter = 0;
  String notificationtext;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }
  @override

    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("bavo");

      _firebaseMessaging.configure(

        onMessage : (Map<String,dynamic> message) {

          print('on message $message');

          setState((){
          _counter = _counter + 100;
          notificationtext = message.toString(); 
          });
        },
        onResume : (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          print('on resume $message');
           setState((){
          _counter = _counter + 100;
          notificationtext = message.toString();
          });
        },
        onLaunch : (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          print('on launch $message');
          setState((){
          _counter = _counter + 100;
          notificationtext = message.toString();
          });
        }, 
      );
      _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
        print(token);

      });
    }
  speak() async {
  flutterTts.speak(notificationtext);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    flutterTts.speak(notificationtext);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
        onPressed: speak,
        child: new Text('Say Hello'),
          ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see in onmessage i set a variable equal to the datapayload of the message and the i let it play with the initstate ( this reloads the widget so it runs the text to speech code, this was to only working way i found)

my problem is how can i make it so if the variable changes it plays it with the text to speech even if the phone is off ,
now it tells it when the app is open and only then

hope you guyss can help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how firebase messaging works, but why not just run the flutterTts.speak() method inside your listener.

Or you can call the speak method within the listener.

I haven't tested this, but might be worth a shot.

example:

```
   onMessage : (Map<String,dynamic> message) {

      print('on message $message');

      setState((){
        _counter = _counter + 100;
        notificationtext = message.toString();
      });
      flutterTts.speak(message.toString());
    },
```

Comment: I have already tried this and now i retried it and it still didn't work, but thnx foer the answer